# iPad SplitView with navigation stack for multiple view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

Hey, 
my starting point was this 
[MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code found on xcode.
I am trying to create a separate navigation stack for the First- and SecondDetailViewController in order to push new view controllers.
A great help was this [tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/) but I still couldn't manage to include the navigation stacks.

I have been stuck on this problem for a while and wonder if there exists a simple solution...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample code, try to open the MainWindow.xib (en) and remove the 'FirstDetailViewController', replace it with a NavigationController, add the rootViewController for this new detail NavigationController and you are good to go.

I guess that you know what to do next. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, I have already replaced the 'FirstDetailViewController' with a NavigationController, changed the NavigationController's DetailViewController to 'FirstDetailViewController' and connected it to the SplitViewController, and so on, as described in the tutorial. When I run the application I can push new views, but as soon as I select another row on the left side of the split view, it doesn't work anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because that sample code replace the DetailViewController with the First & Second respectively when you select an item on the master table list, so you won't have access to the navigation of the FirstDetailViewController anymore. What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to combine the two view controllers into one navigation controller with a root view controller?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What I am trying to achieve is a split view with separate DetailViewControllers (as in the sample code with FirstDetailViewController and SecondDetailViewController). Each DetailViewController should have its own navigation stack to change  the view after pressing a button (as in the tutorial). Hope it became clearer...

Answer (score 0):

looking at this believe i had exactly the same problem and never found a way around it, until a couple of days when i was watching an unrelated lecture off of iTunes U, anyway in the new view controller that you load, have you implemented the UISplitViewControllerDelegate, (if this doesn't work have you tried moving the UISplitViewControllerDelegate to the master controller)?